# Modal pushing conent to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've looked at other questions and answears but can't seem to fix this.

I've got a modal in my page that is shifting the content of my page to the left a little bit.

I've done an example fiddle, its not exactly the same code obviously, but the issue is the same. 
When you click TEST, modal shows up, and it pushes some content.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalContactos1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalContactos1">Contactos</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-1">

            <a class="navbar-brand head" id="contatoshead" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactos" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" title="Contatos" href="#">
              TEST
            </a>

        </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row" id="sidebartest1">
<p>
Test
</p>
</div>

</div>


<main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
<p>
tEST
</p>
</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x38boerf/

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main block in your code has a margin-left property with value of auto. Set that to 0 and it should prevent it from moving.

To clarify, it's being caused by the "ml-sm-auto" class applied to main

Comment: Thanks, that stops pushing the left side to the left, but now it compresses it, pushing only the right side in.

I tried adding a fixed margin-right, but didn't work.

Comment: Set the body width to 100% in your css

Comment: Ye, I got it! I had this "width: calc(100vw - 17px);" on the html, I remember I put it to solve some issue that I guess I sorted out  some other way later and now it was just working against me. 
There is some content on the navbar that still gets pushed tho, but its because of "mx-auto". Any tip on how to make sure that content is centered without using the auto? Thanks for steering me in the right direction by the way!

Comment: If you want the text to be centered, you could use `text-align: center`. If you want the main block to be centered, you'd need to set the width to something less than 100% and use `margin: 0 auto`. The margin property is shorthand for margin top and bottom 0 and margin left and margin right auto. That will force the element into the middle of the page.

Answer (score -1):

```
please add below code in css.

.ml-sm-auto, .mx-sm-auto {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Same issue as the other answear. Now it doesn't push the left side, but the right side gets pushed left, compressing the content. 

Also with this solution my main content goes "above" my sidebar, but I can obviously sort that out by adding some padding. Still, the above issue remains.